# Selection based on several inputs without extreme duplication

Tags: excel

I have a library of data that i need to pull specific rows from, at the moment i have an ID made up of several dropdown menus =$C$2&$F$2... that i compare to an index made up of a combination of column content: =[@Column1]&[@Column2]... that i then use to pull the right data for that instance with VLOOKUP.

Now however i need a much more varied set with more selections, 5 columns worth. That creates 16 sets for every index on the first column and will generate thousands of lines if i am to create one version of every permutation.

The best scenario would be a way to use a modular form of the selections above, if there is any input on X, Y and Z then it functions like now, but if Y and Z are empty it only pulls X. Easy in theory but i dont know the format it will have to take, and it gets even more complicated if i want X and Z for instance, or Y and Z, but still create a neat list of the selections.

An alternative might be a way to pull tables based on a selection, and make one table for every "part" of my query but i cant find a way to do that either.

What i need is any way to pull and combine several rows from a library (based on dropdown or similar input) and assembled in a neat list that i can print.

First post, and thanks in advance =)

Comment: match() with concatenate() and join the columns like that - even with a helper column?

Comment: Match is a good fit for my problems it seems, doesnt solve them but i can use it in part, thanks :D